# select data from database using a logical field

Tags: mysql, database-design

I have the following table in my database:

```
+-------------------+
| rooms             |
+-------------------+
| id                |
| title             |
| single_bed_count  |
| king_bed_count    |
+-------------------+
```

the room's catacity is the sum of single_bed_count and king_bed_count

how can i tell the database that by 'capacity' I mean (single_bed_count + king_bed_count)

by this:

```
SELECT * FROM rooms WHERE capacity = 4;
```

I mean this:

```
SELECT * FROM rooms WHERE single_bed_count + king_bed_count = 4;
```

I want to use this in filtering a resource. What is the best way to implement this?

Comment: Surely a king size bed can hold more than one person?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use either a computed column or a view:

```
create table rooms (
    id int, 
    title varchar(100), 
    single_bed_count int, 
    king_bed_count int,
    bed_count int generated always as (single_bed_count + king_bed_count)
);

insert into rooms (id, title, single_bed_count, king_bed_count)
values
(1, 'room 1', 1, 2),
(2, 'room 2', 2, 2);

select * from rooms;
```

> ```
> id | title  | single_bed_count | king_bed_count | bed_count
> -: | :----- | ---------------: | -------------: | --------:
>  1 | room 1 |                1 |              2 |         3
>  2 | room 2 |                2 |              2 |         4
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=ea1d970325bda50db38839d79d1524d6)*

But have you considered that maybe some day it will be more than 2 room types?

Comment: Thanks a lot. yes, I have considered room_types, this was just an example. but I have a lot of challenge with room_rates. because every room has more than one ratePlans, and every ratePlan has more than one roomRates according to who this room is being sold to. do you know any database design in this field so I can see what others have done and what are the best practices?